# Can inline-block elements be prevented from growing too wide and getting pushed downwards

Tags: javascript, css

https://jsfiddle.net/Ff49Z/118/

```
<div class="container">
    <span class="left_bar">
        aaaaaa<br />
        bbbbbb<br />
        cccccc<br />
    </span>
    <span class="content">
        1 2 3 4 5 55555555555555555555 7777777777777 888888888 11111111111 22222222222222 333333333333333 444444444444444444<br />
        1<br />
        2<br />
        3<br />
        4<br />
        5<br />
        6<br />
        8<br />
    </span>
</div>
```

This works perfectly fine if everything after the first "5" in the first line of the content span was removed (it appears to the right of the "left bar" as desired), but when the line becomes too long, the inline-block element expands to the entire screen and gets pushed below the left bar.

Currently it could be accomplished with a left float and a block element, but I would like to know if there is a solution to this using inline blocks.

Answer (score 2):

Table. Simples! *chirp*

```css
.container{
    display:table;
}
.left_bar {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:top;
}
.content {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <span class="left_bar">
        aaaaaa<br />
        bbbbbb<br />
        cccccc<br />
    </span>
    <span class="content">
        1 2 3 4 5 55555555555555555555 7777777777777 888888888 11111111111 22222222222222 333333333333333 444444444444444444<br />
        1<br />
        2<br />
        3<br />
        4<br />
        5<br />
        6<br />
        8<br />
    </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `white-space: nowrap;`

```
.content {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Ff49Z/122/)**

Answer (score 0):

Add `white-space: nowrap` to your `.container` div. If you want the text in the inline-blocks to wrap, you'll have to set the white-space back to normal.

```css
.container{
    white-space:nowrap;
}
.container > span {
    white-space:normal;
}
.left_bar {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
}
.content {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <span class="left_bar">
        aaaaaa<br />
        bbbbbb<br />
        cccccc<br />
    </span>
    <span class="content">
        1 2 3 4 5 55555555555555555555 7777777777777 888888888 11111111111 22222222222222 333333333333333 444444444444444444<br />
        1<br />
        2<br />
        3<br />
        4<br />
        5<br />
        6<br />
        8<br />
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah! Also add: `.container > span { white-space: normal; }`

Comment: Also, you still have the white space issue between the `left_bar` and `content` elements

Comment: Interesting. I guess because the span is taking 100% width. Table display may be the better option.